# Laravel new project - no home.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, project

My `laravel new project_name` seems to be missing the `home.blade.php` view? Also I noticed that upon creating a project, I used to have all my default routes within the route group and web middleware, and now I only have one route there.

Did someone have the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it's moved to manual command, because some users want to start something different. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authentication-quickstart . Just run command `php artisan make:auth` and everything will be created, what You used to have previously.

Comment: Oh...I knew about the authorization, didn't think it affected the home view also. Then my bash alias is malfunctioning :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since v5.2.27, all routes are automatically use `web` middleware. Also, there is no `home` view now, only `welcome`:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/resources/views

You can run `make:auth` to build `home` view (also auth controllers and auth route).